# New records added in mysqladmin is not displayed in php page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqladmin

I have 300 records in a table of `mysqladmin`, and i am displaying the records in a `php` page,it perfectly works. but when i add new records that is record no. 301,302 and so on, it add the records in table but not getting displayed in `php` page. i using simple query in `php` page,I will just specify the query i used in `php` page.

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM td_table ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

QUESTION UPDATED

```
<?php

       $uq=mysql_query("select user_fullname from td_user where user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."'");
    $u_row=mysql_fetch_object($uq);




    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $condition='1 = 1';
    $q='';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['cname']))
    {

       $q.='&cname='.$_REQUEST['cname'];
      $condition.=" AND Vehicle_description like '%".$_REQUEST['cname']."%'";
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['modelno']))
    {

       $q.='&modelno='.$_REQUEST['modelno'];
      $condition.=" AND Model like '%".$_REQUEST['modelno']."%'";
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['modelno']))
    {

       $q.='&year='.$_REQUEST['year'];
      $condition.=" AND Year like '%".$_REQUEST['year']."%'";
    }
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM td_table where $condition";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "automobile_list.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 1;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = @$_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
       /* $vins = "SELECT SUBSTRING(VIN, 1, 10) FROM td_table"; */

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM td_table where  $condition LIMIT $start, $limit ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&q=$q\">< previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">< previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&q=$q\">$counter</a>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&q=$q\">$counter</a>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&q=$q\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&q=$q\">$lastpage</a>";      
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&q=$q\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&q=$q\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&q=$q\">$counter</a>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&q=$q\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&q=$q\">$lastpage</a>";      
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&q=$q\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&q=$q\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&q=$q\">$counter</a>";                
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next&q=$q\">next ></a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next ></span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>
<!--/menu_section-->

    <div class="paginaton">
            <?php echo $pagination;?>
                  <!--<ul class="paginate clear">
                    <li><a href="">Prev</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>-->
               </div><!--/paginaton-->
   <div class="container">
        <div class="common" style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <?php
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {?>
            <div class="automobilelist">
                <div class="auto_list">

                 <div class="testonepre" style="width:auto;" align="center">
                     <p class="list_head">Vehicle Description</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                   <div class="testone">
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name"> Vehicle Description : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Vehicle_description'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Year : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Year'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Make : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Make'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Model : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Model'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Body Style : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Body_Style'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Trim : </span><span class="list_desc"> <?php echo $row['Trim_Level'];?></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list_text">
                              <span class="list_name">Odometer : </span><span class="list_desc"><?php echo $row['Odometer'];?></span>
```

LIKE this it will dislplay many rows

Comment: Maybe you got cache on php page :)

Comment: are you getting information after insert of before?

Comment: mysql_ APIs were deprecated quite a while ago -- be sure to use mysqli_ (or PDO) to work with more current versions of PHP and avoid security issues!!

Comment: @MarcoMura : i also tried it by clearing the cache.but it doesnt worked up in my case

Comment: @MohamadAttat : no, but i can see the new records added in the table

Comment: can you provide the full code? that'll help identify the issue

Comment: @MohamadAttat : ok i will provide the code, but sorry it is very big code so that i will customize and i will provide the code which has issue.i will update it in question

Comment: did u try the same php query on mysql and is it giving results? if yes then it can be a issue of page caching. just use alt_ctrl_del key and remove your browser histroy from the start and close the browser then re-open the browser. and also run that page on different browser's of your system.

Comment: @Sachin : ya i tried the same query on mysql page.it display all records.the issue is with php page

Comment: where did you close the while loop ??

Comment: @MohamadAttat : i closed it down the code, sorry as i told i cut off the code into half because it is too big

Comment: your problem is that this code is executed before insert into database, tell me if you refresh the page after insert, do the inserted records appear ?

Comment: @MohamadAttat No its not appearing after refreshing,even i cleared the history and cache and tried by opening in a new window but then also its not showing the \newly added records..

Comment: check if(isset($_REQUEST['modelno']))
    {

       $q.='&year='.$_REQUEST['year'];
      $condition.=" AND Year like '%".$_REQUEST['year']."%'";
    } it should be $_REQUEST['year'] right?

Comment: @MohamadAttat : no that is correct my friend..

Comment: when u first hit ur php page, print the $sql variable.

Comment: The problem is with query i wrote,anyone please help me

Comment: i got the solution,mistake is mine in the query i just cleared it.